# How to retrieve the public information by using Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a question about how to retrieve a specific person's information that is set to public by Facebook API (ex: email, location)? My idea is, (the app) to get the information that is set to public without asking the permission from the user.

I understand the Facebook Graph API could help us to retrieve the public_profile (graph.facebook.com/me), but that is very few and limited in v2.0+ (only id,name,first_name,last_name,link,gender,locale,timezone,updated_time,verified). 
I also understand we can use scope in the fb:login-button (in the app) to get the user's permission to access the information. But in that case, since the user has granted it, therefore, even the information is set to private but the app can still access it, which is Not what I need.

In Graph API v1.0, we can use the API call (https://graph.facebook.com/me) to get the basic_info, which includes the information that is set to public. Since the v1.0 has already expired, therefore, I just wonder how I can get the public information by Graph API v2.0+, even other than the Graph API is fine.

Thanks.

Comment: No, you can not get that information unless the user gives your app permission. “Publicly available on Facebook” does not mean publicly available to any 3rd party app.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @CBroe, it's not possible to retrieve such data without the user's permissions. Moreover, the info you are looking for has **always** been locked behind a permission even on v1.0: `email` and `user_location`

If you have a valid reason to ask for this info then explain it in your app and let the users decide.

Ref. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3